# Trial version in Xamarin.Forms application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to implement trial version for my xamarin.forms application. What is the best way to achieve it?

I had an idea to store a unique ID inside the application with help of Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage or inside Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences and compare it with data inside my database at the server, but problem is that all the data getting deleted after each reinstallation of application.

Also, I had an idea to access Xamarin.Essentials.DeviceInfo.Name and verify device name during each application launch, but I'm not sure does this property returns the unique device name during each attempt or not.

I'm new to Xamarin.Forms so I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
        //using Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences
        var id = Preferences.Get("my_id", string.Empty);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            Preferences.Set("my_id", id);
        }


        // using Xamarin.Essentials.SecureStorage
        private async void Save()
        {
          try
          {
            await SecureStorage.SetAsync("bla", "secret-oauth-token- 
         value");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on 
         device.
          }
        }

        private async Task<string> Get()
        {
          try
          {
            return await SecureStorage.GetAsync("bla");
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            // Possible that device doesn't support secure storage on 
          device.
          }

          return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some sort of login? Then you can always just store a key on the server that determines if it is paid. And save on the device for offline use. That way you will know if its a paid version. Otherwise publish a lite version seperate on the store